# How do I open a file that has no extension?

Tags: file

I have a file I put up on my web server once and now I can't remember that extension was it. It is around 119 KB on disk.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That depends on its content. You can view the file in a hex editor (or just windows notepad), the first letters might tell you what kind of file it is. See this list for the file type: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: [Rather short list on Wikipedia for a few formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)

Answer (score 0):

If your server is based on linux, you can try with `**nano namefile**`.

Comment: I downloaded the file from my linux server on my mac.

Answer (score 0):

Post the first part of the file (just some bytes). Often the bytes at the beginning encode the file type.

Comment: I have the original dump code posted in my question, please see above.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it's a JPG file. You can tell by looking up the "magic" number (the first few bytes).

For example, have a look at

http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html

If you use Linux (or another *nix), you can use the "magic" utility (command: "file"). For windows, there is Cygwin which installs suchs utilities for use in Windows.

Comment: Maybe you could post the file, so others here could try.

Comment: I think its a private one so by the name of it I think I shouldnt share it. I kept the name but I cant recall the extension. Moreover, I think its a JPEG file because the HEXCODE matched with the FILE_MAGIC link you sent me. I tried JPEG and it won't show on my mac. How come? The file size is still 119 KB.

Can I reverse engineer the image using the HEXCODE data I have from the HEXCODE Dump app on my Macintosh?